# string::substr() returns a blank string

Tags: c++, string, substring

The next bit of code takes a filename as a string and is supposed to return the name without the extension if the file is a bitmap (extension .bmp).

`InputPicFolder` is a string which contains the path to the input folder.

```
path p(InputPicFolder);
for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
{
    if (!is_directory(i->path())) //eliminate directories
    {
        string filename = i->path().filename().string();
        //string filename = "APicture.bmp"; 
        int len = filename.length();
        if (len > 4)
        {
            size_t found = filename.find('.');
            string EXT = filename.substr(found + 1);
            if (EXT.compare("bmp") == 0) 
            {
                string filenameWOExtension = filename.substr(0, found);
                cout << filenameWOExtension;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an empty string as the output for `filenameWOExtension`

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have a feeling its a pretty silly issue, something my tired eyes cannot see.

edit - Updated the code with the boost part. Doesn't seem to change the result. Even if I overwrite the string by "APicture.bmp", my output's still `""`.

Compiler - MSVC14.1

Comment: Using `boost::filesystem::path` or the new `std` version of it, if available, would be a good idea for those things.

Comment: Did you try (1) printing the value of `found` just before calling `substr`? and (2) making sure your output buffer was flushed before the program stopped?

Comment: I can not [reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k2jRvYcfs8GsRAVx) your issue.

Comment: @RayToal 

(1) I didn't explicitly print it, I'm using the VS debugger to watch the variables.
(2) Trying this

Comment: @Roy2511 What is the value of `found` then?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux filename = "10.bmp" and found = 2, the program is behaving correctly till it gets to the substring of the innermost loop

Comment: @Roy2511 The problem can't be explained by the code you've shared. You'll need to provide more information. You should come up with a [MCVE].

Comment: Is the `EXT.compare()` method case insensitive?

Comment: @Eljay, no it's not.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux please check if edit helps..

Comment: Works for me. I don't have boost but VS2015 compiles the whole code `std::experimental::filesystem` and `std::string`. I doubt if boost has problems with basic `std::string` methods. `filename.substr(found + 1)` is suspicious. There is an error if file length is greater than 4 but there is no extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename = "APicture.bmp"; // *** I Changed this
    int len = filename.length();
    if (len > 4)
    {
        size_t found = filename.find('.');
        string EXT = filename.substr(found + 1);
        if (EXT.compare("bmp") == 0)
        {
            string filenameWOExtension = filename.substr(0, found); //should be "APicture"
            cout << filenameWOExtension;
        }
    }
}
```

The only change I made was to how you got your source string.  Is it possible that you aren't searching in the string you think you are?

If my complete program doesn't produce the output: `APicture` you should provide more information on your compiler and runtime environment.  This compiles with the std::string interface, but is it an actual std::string or something made to act like one?

Further, why use compare() instead of ordinary == to compare 2 strings?

Comment: No, the filenames are directly from boost. 

Compiler - MSVC14.1

The filename var is actually a std::string